# The ajax file cannot pass the file field value to the php file

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have problem with the ajax file. The ajax file does not work with the php form.
when I run the code it displays an error file_get_content error, file name empty.

The php code is working properly. but the ajax file cannot transfer the file field value.
So the file cannot attach with mail.

it shows the error: file name empty

plz help me to pass the file field value through the ajax file.

```
<div>
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"     action="contactus.php" onsubmit="xmlhttpPost('contactus.php', 'form1', 'Myresult', ''); return false;">
Name:<input name="name1" type="text"   value="" />
Address:<input name="address1" type="text"  value="" /> 
Phone:<input name="phone1" type="text" value=""/>
Email: <input name="email1" type="text" value="" />
File:<input name="file" type="file" size="35" id="file" />
Links:<input name="links1" type="text" value="" />
Subject:<input name="subject1" type="text" value="" />
Location:<select name="location">
              <option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>

Comments:<textarea name="comment1"  ></textarea>
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit"/>   
<div id="Myresult"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

php form(contactus.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

 $name=$_POST['name1'];
$address=$_POST['address1'];
$phone=$_POST['phone1'];
$email=$_POST['email1'];
$subject=$_POST['subject1'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$comment=$_POST['comment1'];
$links=$_POST['links1'];

$to='mail@mail.com';

 $message .= "\nName: ".$name."\n\n";
 $message .= "Address: ".$address."\n\n";
 $message .= "Phone: ".$phone."\n\n";
 $message .= "Email: ".$email."\n\n";
  $message .= "Links: ".$links."\n\n";
  $message .= "Location: ".$location."\n\n";
  $message .= "Comments:\n\n ".$comment."\n";



$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];        
    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

$headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\nReply-To: $name <$email>";
$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";


$message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

  --_1_$boundary
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

 --_2_$boundary
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 $message

 --_2_$boundary--
 --_1_$boundary
 Content-Type: $filetype; name=\"$filename\" 
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
 Content-Disposition: attachment 

 $attachment

 --_1_$boundary--";

 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

 print 'Thanks, your message sent!';

 }

 ?>
```

ajax.js

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL, formname, responsediv, responsemsg) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Xhr per Mozilla/Safari/Ie7
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // per tutte le altre versioni di IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            // Quando pronta, visualizzo la risposta del form
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText, responsediv);
        } else {
            // In attesa della risposta del form visualizzo il msg di attesa
            updatepage(responsemsg, responsediv);
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring(formname));
}

function getquerystring(formname) {
    var form = document.forms[formname];
    var qstr = "";

    function GetElemValue(name, value) {
        qstr += (qstr.length > 0 ? "&" : "") + escape(name).replace(/\+/g, "%2B") + "=" + escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
        //+ escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\n/g, "%0D");
    }

    var elemArray = form.elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++) {
        var element = elemArray[i];
        var elemType = element.type.toUpperCase();
        var elemName = element.name;
        if (elemName) {
            if (elemType == "TEXT" || elemType == "TEXTAREA" || elemType == "PASSWORD" || elemType == "BUTTON" || elemType == "RESET" || elemType == "SUBMIT" || elemType == "FILE" || elemType == "IMAGE" || elemType == "HIDDEN")

            GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);
            else if (elemType == "CHECKBOX" && element.checked) GetElemValue(elemName,
            element.value ? element.value : "On");
            else if (elemType == "RADIO" && element.checked) GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);
            else if (elemType.indexOf("SELECT") != -1)

            for (var j = 0; j < element.options.length; j++) {
                var option = element.options[j];
                if (option.selected) GetElemValue(elemName,
                option.value ? option.value : option.text);
            }
        }
    }
    return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str, responsediv) {
    document.getElementById(responsediv).innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: What's with the whitespace everywhere? It's so hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce your error. Try this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {

        $name     = $_POST['name1'];
        $address  = $_POST['address1'];
        $phone    = $_POST['phone1'];
        $email    = $_POST['email1'];
        $subject  = $_POST['subject1'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        $comment  = $_POST['comment1'];
        $links    = $_POST['links1'];

        $to = 'mail@mail.com';

        $message .= "\nName: " . $name . "\n\n";
        $message .= "Address: " . $address . "\n\n";
        $message .= "Phone: " . $phone . "\n\n";
        $message .= "Email: " . $email . "\n\n";
        $message .= "Links: " . $links . "\n\n";
        $message .= "Location: " . $location . "\n\n";
        $message .= "Comments:\n\n " . $comment . "\n"; 

        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
        $filename   = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $filetype   = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $boundary   = md5(date('r', time()));

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\nReply-To: $name <$email>";
        $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

          --_1_$boundary
         Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

         --_2_$boundary
         Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
         Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

         $message

         --_2_$boundary--
         --_1_$boundary
         Content-Type: $filetype; name=\"$filename\" 
         Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
         Content-Disposition: attachment 

         $attachment

         --_1_$boundary--";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        print 'Thanks, your message sent!';
        exit;
    }

    print 'Some error';
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function xmlhttpPost(strURL, formname, responsediv, responsemsg) {
            var xmlHttpReq = false;
            var self = this;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest()
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
            self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
                    updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText, responsediv)
                } else {
                    updatepage(responsemsg, responsediv)
                }
            }
            self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring(formname))
        }
        function getquerystring(formname) {
            var form = document.forms[formname];
            var qstr = "";

            function GetElemValue(name, value) {
                qstr += (qstr.length > 0 ? "&" : "") + escape(name).replace(/\+/g, "%2B") + "=" + escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\+/g, "%2B")
            }
            var elemArray = form.elements;
            for (var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++) {
                var element = elemArray[i];
                var elemType = element.type.toUpperCase();
                var elemName = element.name;
                if (elemName) {
                    if (elemType == "TEXT" || elemType == "TEXTAREA" || elemType == "PASSWORD" || elemType == "BUTTON" || elemType == "RESET" || elemType == "SUBMIT" || elemType == "FILE" || elemType == "IMAGE" || elemType == "HIDDEN") GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);
                    else if (elemType == "CHECKBOX" && element.checked) GetElemValue(elemName, element.value ? element.value : "On");
                    else if (elemType == "RADIO" && element.checked) GetElemValue(elemName, element.value);
                    else if (elemType.indexOf("SELECT") != -1) for (var j = 0; j < element.options.length; j++) {
                            var option = element.options[j];
                            if (option.selected) GetElemValue(elemName, option.value ? option.value : option.text)
                    }
                }
            }
            return qstr
        }
        function updatepage(str, responsediv) {
            document.getElementById(responsediv).innerHTML = str
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="xmlhttpPost('', 'form1', 'Myresult', ''); return false;">
                <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit">
                <div id="Myresult"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry friend.. its ma mistake..
actually the div name is corect in my code..
<div id="Myresult"></div>

Comment: my problem with this code is I cannot recieve the response in that html page...

Comment: I tested it and it seems to retrieve the page fine. Make sure `contactus.php` responds with something regardless if `$_POST['submit1']` is set or not.

Comment: thank you.. let me try..

Comment: i changed my code from if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) to if (isset($_POST['submit'])) and also changed in html submit,
bt now shows warning error file_get_contents() and now i can not upload file to the mail.

Comment: Please show html code. What is the upload element named in the html form?

Comment: <input name="file" type="file" size="35" id="file" value="" />

Comment: error shows on file_get_contents line.
warning: empty file name

Comment: Now it shows the file_get_content error, file name empty.
I think the ajax file cannot pass the file field value to the php file.